# Customize local network access (LNA) interstitial dialog UI

Tags: ios, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

The first time a user attempts to Cast, a new local network access (LNA) interstitial dialog will appear explaining why local networking access is needed. The dialog contains **Learn more** button which links to Google's support web page. Apple requires that apps that target kids can not link outside the app so is there a way to remove **Learn more** button or disable the interstitial dialog?

[image]